# RUST-based weather logger. Makes HTTP request to get a JSON and write to .csv

Tags: rust

I've recently attempted to get into rust. I thought I would try convert my weather logging app from python to rust to maybe save some CPU cycles on my little Raspberry Pi.

I have a little ESP8266 with a web server that allows you to pull data from it, it returns a JSON:

```
{
  "Readings": {
    "temperature": 23.62999916,
    "humidity": 55.01464844,
    "pressure": 1025.828003
  }
}
```

Now, I spent the best part of a few hours going from never having used rust before, to getting this program working and I feel like it is... not good. I'm still confused how to get error propagation working correctly. I feel as though my solution is not the standard way this would be done!

Any input is welcome, here is my code:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::{Write, Result};
use std::path::Path;
use reqwest;

// Struct to hold the readings from the ESP8266
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Readings {
    temperature: f32,
    humidity: f32,
    pressure: f32,
}

// Makes a request to the ESP8266 and returns the readings
async fn make_request() -> std::result::Result<Readings, reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::Client::new()
    .get("http://192.168.0.190/json")
    .send()
    .await?;

    let json_str = response.text().await?;
    let json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&json_str).unwrap();
    let reading: Readings = serde_json::from_value(json["Readings"].clone()).unwrap();

    Ok(reading)
}

// Writes the data obtained from the make_request() function to a CSV file
fn write_to_csv(data: &Readings) -> Result<()> {
    let path = Path::new("data/weather.csv");

    // Check if file exists, if not create it and add headers
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(true)
        .open(path)?;

    if file.metadata()?.len() == 0 {
        writeln!(file, "timestamp,temperature,humidity,pressure")?;
    }

    // Get the current UTC time
    let timestamp: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();

    // Write the data with timestamp to the CSV file
    writeln!(file, "{},{},{},{}", timestamp, data.temperature, data.humidity, data.pressure)?;

    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main(){    
    // Make the request and write the data to the CSV file
    let reading = make_request().await.unwrap();
    _ = write_to_csv(&reading);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is error propagation. What you want is an error type that can handle multiple possible errors. The simplest way to get one is to use a crate that provides it. I like `color-eyre` because it gives me colored stack traces to help track error. Another crate `anyhow` is popular as well.

To use color_eyre, I add the following use statement:

```
use color_eyre::Result;
```

Now, I'd define my functions to return this Result like so:

```
async fn make_request() -> Result<Readings> {
```

Inside, `make_request()` the `?` operator will automatically convert most any error into a `color_eyre::Report`. This means that I can use it both for errors from `reqwest` and `serde_json`  even though they produce different error types.

For the main function, I do something like this:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {    
    color_eyre::install()?;
    // Make the request and write the data to the CSV file
    let reading = make_request().await?;
    write_to_csv(&reading)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Notice that I return the `Result` type. This will automatically do the right thing of return an error status and outputting a stack trace to stderr.

When you parse the object, you do in two stages, first to a json object, then you parse out the inner object.

```
let json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&json_str)?;
let reading: Readings = serde_json::from_value(json["Readings"].clone())?;
```

It's ok, but not fantastic. I'd define a struct to represent the whole response:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct ApiResponse {
    readings: Readings
}
let json: ApiResponse = serde_json::from_str(&json_str)?;
Ok(json.readings)
```

Notice that you can define a struct inside a function. In this case it makes sense because the only reason to aid in parsing the response. This will work a bit better in terms of better errors (it won't panic in trying to read a non-existent json item and performance (it'll parse directly into the struct instead of a json object first.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for, thank you! I knew I was doing error propagation poorly... I will look into those error handlers and implement your suggestions. I especially like using the struct for my API response. I tried doing something like that but couldn't get it to work myself!